# Why is the character occurence program working and the total count don't?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, addeventlistener

I have this exercise in my course where they ask us to create a function that counts all the characters in a random text and to count all the occurences of each character in that text.

I tried to do all of that and i have both codes done, but i can't make them work in the website.

1. function to count all the characters in the box (textarea total characters) - this doesnt work
2. function to count the occurrences of each character in the box (text area total occurrences of a character  - this works

```js
let myText = document.getElementById("my-text");

myText.addEventListener("input", () => {
  let count = (myText.value).length;
  document.getElementById("count-result").textContent = `Character count: ${count}`;
});


function search() {
  var myText = document.getElementById("my-text").value;
  //console.log(textareaValue);

  var characterToSearch = document.getElementById("characterToFind").value;
  //console.log(characterToSearch);
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++) {
    if (characterToSearch == myText[i]) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("totalCharacters").innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>Introduce el texto que desees</label>
  <br>
  <textarea id="my-text" placeholder="escribe un texto"></textarea>
  <h1 id="count-result">Character Count: </h1>
  <br>
  <label>Qué letra quieres que encontremos?</label>
  <br>
  <textarea placeholder="añade el caracter que quieres" id="characterToFind"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="search();" value="Search">
  <br>
  <label>Veces repetida : </label><label id="totalCharacters"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet where it appears to work fine. For example, if you type `aaabbbccc` in the first box, then search for `a` in the second, the result is 3. Can you please edit your question to give details of whatever the issue you have is. If you're struggling to debug this, I'd suggest first checking devtools in your local version

Comment: Hey Rory, my problem with this is that the total character count does not work. The number of occurences of each character in the box is not the problem. The problem is that when you type in that box,  the total number of characters does not appear automatically on the screen

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense, I'm afraid. Can you please edit the question to include the steps required to demonstrate the issue you have, along with the expected output from that case.

Comment: they ask for two things, a function that counts all the characters in the text area (does not work), and the second one, the function (this one works) that counts the occurrences of a character.

Comment: This is why I'm confused what you're asking. If you click the big blue button under the snippet to run it, you will see your code is *already working*